# Mutual information with two independent variables

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let us say we have three random variables, $A$, $B$, and $C$, where $A$ and $B$ are independent. I know that $$I(A;B) = 0.$$ Also, my intuition is that $$I(A;B,C) = I(A;C).$$
However, I cannot either prove or disprove this. Is my intuition correct?

UPD: the question has been answered. See also a follow-up [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091971/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not** true. Take $A,B$ to be two independent Rademacher random variables, i.e., uniform on $\{-1,1\}$; and let $C=AB$.

$A,B$ are independent, so $I(A;B) = 0$. Similarly, $A,C$ are independent, so that $I(A;C) = 0$. However, $A=BC$, so $I(A;(B,C)) = 1 \neq 0$.

*(Instead of Rademacher, if you prefer you can equivalently consider $A,B$ to be two independent uniformly random bits, and let $C=A\oplus B$ be their XOR. This is literally the same.)*

Comment: Completely agree. Btw, random bits example looks easier/more intuitive to me, personally.

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka To me as well, but multiplication might be more appealing to some than addition in $\mathrm{GF}_2$.

Comment: But at least the following is correct, right? $I(A;B,C) = I(A;C|B)$.

Comment: I can't answer now (commuting). However, you may want to post this as a new question, and link to this one (instead of updating). @YauhenYakimenka

Comment: @Cllement C. The link to the new question has been added.

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka Looks like you solved it :)